# Phonegap-android: location.reload() does not fire deviceready event

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

In Phonegap 1.1.0 - android when you call window.location.reload(), the deviceready event is not fired. Has anyone experienced the same problem? Is there any solution for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the pattern:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

then:

```
window.onLoad = () ->
    document.addEventListener "deviceready", onDeviceReady, false
```

?

Comment: i am using jquery so I used document ready event, but the point is more than less the same:
$(document).ready(function(){
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});